# Earn bounty after grace period if accepted in specific use case (review mode)

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I read many Questions related to mine. Some of them were about something I want to share, but not in 100%.

Let's consider situation that I asked a question with the bounty. Somebody answered the question, but my question was so specific, that nobody else upvoted the answer of that guy instead of me (not enough score to earn bounty). So I can think that is not the best answer and I'm afraid of awarding this guy with bounty, just because nobody were able to go into this problem and check if it's really the best answer (upvote). Maybe we should create review queue for that cases, because some of them need real experts? And these kind of questions will land there after grace period?

I'm not asking for the infinity grace period. I also don't buy if somebody tells me, that "this system works in this way, let it go...". It's not an argument. Let's discuss.

Comment: If you set a bounty you should award that bounty based on *your* judgment, not the perceived judgment of others (i.e. don't base it on votes alone—or at all).

Comment: And what if somebody set bounty, but not for giving it anybody, but just only to pay attention on his question? It's still unfair for person who spend a lot of time on answering the question.

Comment: If you want to reward someone for spending the time to answer your question then that is fine, but you don't need votes to justify doing that.

Comment: @Cai no, I'm taking about different use case, please read my last comment here carefully.

Comment: How? Because it isn't automatically awarded? If you feel it should be then award it yourself, you shouldn't need votes to judge the quality of an answer.

Comment: @Cai how can I award it myself if I'm not OP? But only answering the question.

Comment: You don't. OP does. Your question says "consider situation that *I* asked a question", so that's the perspective I was thinking of, but it does't matter—If your answer is deserving of the bounty then OP should award it to you, simple as that.

Comment: The point is, there is already a mechanism for awarding bounties that aren't manually awarded and bountied questions already get their own "featured" tab so they get enough attention. We shouldn't be adding review queues unless there is a *very* good reason to do so.

Comment: Of course I can't and I know that. We have to define, what does it mean "deserving of the bounty" by having in mind situation I described in my question and this is all about.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's a good idea. If you start a bounty, the only person that should decide which answer gets the bounty is *you*. It's entirely your choice. You don't have to choose some answer only because other people upvoted it. You should choose the answer that helped *you* most.

Comment: It's not true what you're writing, because system do that according to second person decision after the grace period isn't it? So you're not the only one person who do that (score 2, if you won't award anybody).

Comment: @turkus You award it **before** the grace period ends. Then it's your choice. If you wait too long the system will award it and it is no longer your choice.

Comment: @Gothdo it's obvious. But it's not a topic of my case.